# Cannot Kicking a member python telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

Hi i have a problem with kick my friend from my group and channel. I would like to remove it from my channel or group via telethon api. I have some problem: `Telegram doesn’t actually have a request to kick a user from a group. Instead, you need to restrict them so they can’t see messages. Any date is enough:`

https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/chats-and-channels.html#kicking-a-member

I try use this code

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import EditBannedRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChatBannedRights

client = TelegramClient(self.phone, self.api_id, self.api_hash)
client(EditBannedRequest("myChannelName", "myFriendUserName", ChatBannedRights(
        until_date=None,
        view_messages=True
)))
```

I got error `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChatWriteForbiddenError: You can't write in this chat (caused by EditBannedRequest)`

How can I remove user from telegram group or channel via telethon or some diffrent ways

Answer (score 0):

you could only kick them, but i don't think it's the case, for "banning people" you should do:

```
from datetime import timedelta
await client.edit_permissions(chat_entity, user_entity, view_messages=False)
```

as said in the [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/)

Comment: This is the same error message client.edit_permissions("myGroup", "myUser", view_messages=False)
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChatWriteForbiddenError: You can't write in this chat (caused by EditBannedRequest)